# Customer Collection Object Not Instantiated

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer

This might be a stupid question :)
`Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Parser_Customer` has the following method:

```
protected $_collections;

public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    if (!isset($this->_collections[$storeId])) {
        $this->_collections[$storeId] = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
        $this->_collections[$storeId]->getEntity()->setStore($storeId);
    }
    return $this->_collections[$storeId];
}
```

I am writing a custom Observer. I emulate the code above as follows:

```
class Jongosi_Module_Model_Observer
{
    protected $_collections;
    public function getCustomerCollection($storeId = 1)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_collections[$storeId])) {
            $this->_collections[$storeId] = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
            $this->_collections[$storeId]->getEntity()->setStore($storeId);
        }
        return $this->_collections[$storeId];
    }
}
```

Obviously, my class doesn't extend anything. I get the following instantiation error:

```
Call to a member function getEntity() on a non-object in ... on line 8
```

But the object is instantiated on line 7, yes?

What am I not doing? Thanks.

### ~ edit ~

The following *does* work though, unsurprisingly:

```
class Jongosi_Module_Model_Observer
{
    protected $_collections;
    public function getCustomerCollection($storeId = 1)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_collections[$storeId])) {
            $test = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
            foreach ($test as $t) {
                var_dump($t->getData());
            }
        }
        return $this->_collections[$storeId];
    }
}
```

The observer is called by the `controller_action_predispatch` event in my `config.xml` file as follows:

```
...
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <jongosi_module>
                    <class>jongosi_module/observer</class>
                    <method>getCustomerCollection</method>
                </jongosi_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
...
```

I am obviously going to change the method that is called, but I was starting with baby steps :) This code is all part of a custom module.

Comment: Something else is going on. Next debug step is to check that `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');` works.

Comment: Thx Ben, that contains object(Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection)#98 (33), as expected. I've edited my question.

Comment: Ok, then try: `echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->getEntity());`...

Comment: I'm a little confused by this question (maybe it's been edited since) — what event are you listening for?

Comment: @Alan I'm listening for the frontend `controller_action_predispatch` event.

Comment: @Jongosi What's the value of `$storeId`? i.e. How are you calling this method?

Comment: @Alan, thx for following this up. I have edited the question with more details. At the moment, `$storeId` is not provided - defaults to `1`. I have checked this and my default store id is `1`. Thx.

Comment: Thx Alan and benmarks for following this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you've got multiple things going wrong here.

First, an observer method has one, and only one argument, the observer object (usually represented by an `$observer` variable).  So your `$storeId` variable actually has a `Varien_Event_Observer` object inside of it at the start of your method.  Then, your code attempts to use that object as an array key.

PHP doesn't allow objects to be used as array keys.  If you have your site in developer mode (in `index.php` look for `setDeveloperMode`) you'd get an illegal offset warning.  Since you're not in developer mode PHP keeps quiet about the error, but nothing gets set in your array.

All this means `$this->_collections[$storeId]` returns `null`, which means

```
$this->_collections[$storeId]->getEntity()
```

triggers an error.

Second — that bit of code from `Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Parser_Customer` doesn't look like it's current.  The `getEntity` method will return a  `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer` object — which has no `setStore` method.  So even if you could ignore the above, your code is still going to cause an error.

Third — your observer doesn't DO anything.  It returns a collection, but Magento doesn't do anything with return values from observers.

Hopefully that helps point you in the right direction to solve whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: It certainly does, thanks for all the info Alan!